# How to create custom CSV files using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

In the **$csv_array_attributes[0]** represents every column for my csv file. **sku** is the product id. In **$csv_array_attributes[0]** represents all of the product ids for my csv(which is the rows value form column **sku**). In the query below I extract all of the products ids, attributes names and attributes values. My problem is that I have to compute my **$csv array** in order to assign for each attribute name(columns) the **attribute values**. In **$final_string** somehow I want to memorize all of the attributes values for a products (**see the commented part**). Thx in advance for the help. Im really stuck with this :(

```
           $csv_array_attributes[0] = "sku%%".$header; 
                    //GETTING ATTRIBUTES VALUES
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($xml->children() as $content){
                        $id_produs = $content->ProductCode;
                        $csv_array_attributes[$i] = $id_produs;
                        $i++;
                    }


                    $select = mysql_query("SELECT  id_prod.id_produs, GROUP_CONCAT('^^',nume_attr) AS nume_at, GROUP_CONCAT('^^',val_attr) AS val_at FROM attributes 
                    INNER JOIN id_prod   
                    ON id_prod.id_id_produs = attributes.id_produs 
                    GROUP BY id_prod.id_produs");
                    $i = 0;  $id_prod = array();
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
                        $id_produs = $row['id_produs'];
                        $nume_attr = explode(",^^",substr($row['nume_at'],2));
                        $val_attr = explode(",^^",substr($row['val_attr'],2));
                        $id_prod[$id_produs] = $nume_attr;
                        $i++;
                    }
                    // var_dump(count($id_prod));
                    $nume = explode("%%", $csv_array_attributes[0]);
                    $csv[0] = $csv_array_attributes[0];


                    $i = 1;
                    foreach ($id_prod as $key => $value) {
    // comment part
                    //$final_string = "";
                    //if (attr_name has attribute_value for product i ){
                            //     $final_string.= attribute_value."%%";
                    //}else{
                            //      $final_string.= "%%";
                     //}
   //end comment part
                        $csv[$i] = $csv_array_attributes[$i]."%%".$final_string;
                        $i++;
                    }
                    //var_dump($csv_array_attributes[0])
                    //CREARE CSV
                    $file = fopen("attributes.csv","w+");
                    foreach ($csv as $line){
                        fputcsv($file,explode('%%',$line),"^","`");
                    }
```

To see the current result please click [HERE](http://attin.netlogiq.eu/it4profit/test.php)

Comment: there are 2800 product ids and 2000 attribute names(columns), I forgot to mention it :|

Answer (score 0):

Actually I only can give you a hint how I would create a array for csv.

```
// header
$csv[0][0] = "one";
$csv[0][1] = "two";
$csv[0][2] = "three";
$csv[0][3] = "four";
$csv[0][4] = "five";

// body
$csv[1][0] = "some";
$csv[1][1] = "values";
$csv[1][2] = "that";
$csv[1][3] = "could";
$csv[1][4] = "be";

$csv[2][0] = "here";
$csv[2][1] = "in";
$csv[2][2] = "this";
$csv[2][3] = "little";
$csv[2][4] = "array";
```

*This is only a sample to view the array setup.*

If you have set up the header, lets say by a `for` you can fill the 2 demensional array.
If this is set up you can use a `foreach` to build your CSV

**Sample**

```
$seperator  = ";";
$ln         = "\r\n";
$csv_output = "";
foreach($csv as $c){
    foreach($c as $value){
        $csv_output .= $value . $seperator;
    }
    $csv_output . $ln;
}
```

csv output

```
one;two;three;four;five;
some;values;that;could;be;
here;in;this;little;array;
a row;with an;;empty;field;
```

empty fields are no problem since you seperate them all with a `;`

Comment: but I have to check also if there is no value for row x to column y and leave it empty

Comment: using this code also to create my csv: $csv_output = explode(";", $csv_output);
 $file = fopen("attributes.csv","w+");
 fputcsv($file,$csv_output);   I got all of that content in the first row

Comment: where do you receive your main data from  to create that csv ? ps: `explode` doesn't recognize linebreaks. See [fgetcsv](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for this

Comment: I dont want to get data from csv I want to create data and put it in csv file and Im using fputcsv

Comment: i asked you, where you get your raw data from. Are you selecting it from a DB or what? and how does the raw data you recive and trying to create a csv from looks like ? I just want to know/see the data you get to create a csv from.